# Не получается сделать полноценную json десериализацию

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

От стороннего сервиса приходит примерно такая json строка:

```
{"FromCity" : [[100510000863, {"n":"Москва", "t" : [2,2,3]}],
[100510001075, {"n":"Санкт-Петербург", "t" : [1,3,1]}]],

"ToCountries" : [[100420695633, {"n":"Абхазия"}],
[100410646680, {"n":"Австрия"}],
[100431113927, {"n":"Андорра"}]]}
```

В параметре FromCity указан код города, название и массив, в котором указано, как можно добраться до страны из параметра ToCountries. Где индекс массива соответствует порядковому номеру страны, а значение указывает на тип сообщения (1 - нет, 2 - самолет, 3 - поезд).
Пытаюсь сделать десериализацию в класс Directions, но пока получается коряво. Visual Studio предлагает сделать вот такой простой класс:

```
public class Directions
{
    public object[][] FromCity { get; set; }
    public object[][] ToCountries { get; set; }
}
```

Десериализация проходит нормально, но потом приходится делать дополнительную десериализацию для некоторых отдельных элементов массива, а именно для строк типа: {"n":"Австрия"} или {"n":"Москва", "t" : [2,2,3]}, т.к. они хранятся в массиве просто в виде строки. И только после этого получается сделать полноценный класс Directions с взаимосвязанными элементами.

Есть ли возможность сделать десериализацию только за счет правильного описания структуры класса, без дополнительного допиливания напильником?

Comment: А в какое поле вы большие числа писать собираетесь? `100510000863`

Comment: @tym32167 после 1-й десериализации, это тип object, потом его можно преобразовать в другой.

Comment: Обратите внимание на ваш json - у вас там в одном массиве рядом стоят число и json объект, потому мне и не ясно, во что вы этот массив хотите десериализовать.

Comment: @tym32167 Тут напрашивается Dictionary, где ключом будет число, а значением json объект. Я пробовал такой вариант, но десериализация проходила с ошибкой, т.к. для успешной десериализации,  для числа нужно указать, что это "key", а для данных "value".

Comment: @Advarus Советую воспользоваться [данным](https://app.quicktype.io) ресурсом. Он составит структуру классов, а также все необходимые конверторы для корректной десериализации JSON.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ссылку, я когда искал ответ в аналогичных вопросах как у меня, встретил ссылку на этот инструмент, но, к сожалению, код, который он сгенерировал оказался нерабочий, происходила ошибка при десериализации. Так что пока разбираюсь что не так.

Comment: @Advarus Значит что то делаете не так, либо в коде JSON не полный. Проверил у себя на пустом проекте с сгенерированным кодом, все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json.Net` поддерживает LINQ, поэтому можно поработать так:

1) создадим такой класс

```
class Direction
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

2) и примерно так можно разобрать ваш json на две коллекции этого класса, даю как пример, напильником вы уж там сами подработайте...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("==Miscl==");
    Console.WriteLine();

    //читаем файл
    string fileName = "json1.json";
    string pathFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\..", fileName);
    string json = File.ReadAllText(pathFile);

    //первый уровень - массив из значений "FromCity" и "ToCountries"
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    var childrenArrays = jObject.Children().ToArray();

    //создаем коллекцию из значений "FromCity"
    List<Direction> FromCityDirections = new List<Direction>();
    foreach (var level1 in childrenArrays[0])
    {
        foreach (var level2 in level1.ToArray())
        {
            var dir = new Direction
            {
                Code = (string)level2[0],
                Name = (string)level2[1]["n"],
                Numbers = level2[1]["t"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList()
            };

            FromCityDirections.Add(dir);
        }
    }

    //создаем коллекцию из значений "ToCountries"
    List<Direction> ToCountryDirections = new List<Direction>();
    foreach (var level1 in childrenArrays[1])
    {
        foreach (var level2 in level1.ToArray())
        {
            var dir = new Direction
            {
                Code = (string)level2[0],
                Name = (string)level2[1]["n"],
                Numbers = new List<string>()
            };

            ToCountryDirections.Add(dir);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, примерно так и реализовал в итоге, только я использовал вместо списка словарь. Я просто думал, что возможно, есть способ решить эту задачу чисто правильным описанием класса, в который будет происходить десериализация, ведь мне эта json строка приходит извне, значит кто-то делал обратный процесс, а значит есть какая-то структура данных из которой она формируется .

Comment: Пожалуйста. Такое предположение имеет место быть, но довольно часто из результата тяжело в лоб и сразу сконструировать исходник. Гораздо проще начать разбирать и анализировать по частям.